# If 2 triggered abilities occur at the same time, can I play an instant before the 2nd trigger resolves?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a Derevi Blink deck...

I had [Spark Double](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=spark%20double) copy [Derevi](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=derevi%2C%20empyrial%20tactician) and have [Skyward Eye Prophets](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/details.aspx?multiverseid=174953) on the field.

The when nothing as summoning sickness, I tap Skyward to have my draw or play a land. When I go to combat and attack with both Derevis will their triggers go on the stack to be resolved one at a time? If so can I resolve the 1st to untap Skyward, then in response to the 2nd Derevi trigger tap Skyward again, then let the 2nd Derevi trigger resolve to use Skyward effect for a 3rd and final time?

Comment: Note that if you connect with both Deveris, you will get *four* triggers, not just two. Each of them sees two creatures deal combat damage to a player, so each of them triggers twice. You can interleave activating the Prophet in between each of these untaps, as GendoIkari says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. After a spell or ability on the stack resolves, each player gets priority again before the next thing on the stack resolves, so you will have the chance to activate abilities or cast instants after the first trigger resolves.

Do note that you have to choose targets when putting the triggered abilities on the stack, so you will have to choose to target Skyward Eye Prophets with both of the triggered abilities as you put them on the stack.